# Initialise a functor passed into a unique_ptr custom deleter

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, raii

I'm using RAII to manage resources in my code by making use of `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleters. So far this has been relatively trivial, but I now want to add an RAII-wrapper for a resource which requires access to an existing managed resource as part of its cleanup functor.

To break it down, I have one class which has an RAII-managed resource and can acquire additional resources which depend on it:

```
struct CloseHandleFunctor
{
    typedef HANDLE pointer;
    void operator()(const HANDLE h)
    {
        ::CloseHandle(h);
    }
};

using AutoHandle = std::unique_ptr<HANDLE, CloseHandleFunctor>;

class Helper
{
public:
    // acquires a resource associated with h_
    Resource get_resource();
    // releases the resource acquired by get_resource()
    void release_resource(const Resource res);
    // ...
private:
    AutoHandle h_;
};
```

I want to wrap the `Resource` returned by `Helper::get_resource()`, but can't work out how to use `std::unique_ptr` to provide access to the instance of the `Helper` class within the functor:

```
struct ReleaseResourceFunctor
{
    typedef Resource pointer;
    void operator()(Helper h, const Resource r)
    {
        h.release_resource(r);
    }
};

using AutoResource = std::unique_ptr<Resource, ReleaseResourceFunctor>;
   // no way to pass the instance of Helper ~~~^
```

This is how I would like to use it:

```
int main()
{
    Helper h;

    {
        AutoResource res(h.get_resource());
    }
    // h.release_resource() gets called
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible in a single step, you probably have to [get the deleter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get_deleter) and have a function in the deleter structure to set the helper class.

Comment: These are nested lifetimes, I see no problem?

Comment: Store a reference/pointer to the `Helper` instance in `ReleaseResourceFunctor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000562/initialise-a-functor-passed-into-a-unique-ptr-custom-deleter#comment44390349_28000562) and [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000562/initialise-a-functor-passed-into-a-unique-ptr-custom-deleter#comment44390963_28000562), I can get it working by storing a pointer to the instance of the `Helper` class in the functor:

```
struct ReleaseResourceFunctor
{
    typedef Resource pointer;

    Helper *helper_;

    ReleaseResourceFunctor()
        : helper_(nullptr)
    {
    }

    void setHelper(Helper * const h)
    {
        helper_ = h;
    }

    void operator()(const Resource r)
    {
        if (helper_ != nullptr)
        {
            helper_->release_resource(r);
        }
    }
};
```

...and then by assigning the helper instance after constructing the `std::unique_ptr`:

```
int main()
{
    Helper h;

    {
        AutoResource res(h.get_resource());
        res.get_deleter().setHelper(&h);
    }
    // h.release_resource() gets called as expected
}
```

It seems a little fragile (remembering to assign the helper instance each time), but it does work as expected.